# Java Calendar - getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek but not from get instance

Tags: java, calendar

i'm trying to send month as int to a method that will bring me back the minimal days of the first week.
the problem is it bring me back always the same answer. it seems it ignore from my calendar i created in order to do so. please advice:

**MyPanel send the int to the method:**

```
public JPanel getCenter()

{
    //int curMonth = getMonthFromCombo();
    int curMonth = 4;
    int curYear = getYearFromCombo();
    int countDays = 1;
    int MinDaysFirstWeek = myDate.getMinDaysFirstWeek(curYear, curMonth - 1, 1);
    System.out.println("min days are:" + MinDaysFirstWeek);
    int daysInCurMoth = myDate.getHowManyDaysInCurMonth(curYear , curMonth - 1, 1);
    System.out.println("current month:" + curMonth);
    System.out.println("days in current month:" + daysInCurMoth);
    JPanel center = new JPanel();
```

**method needs to send back the minimal days of the first week to the panel:**

```
public int getMinDaysFirstWeek(int curYear , int curMonth , int day)
{
    Calendar forDay = new GregorianCalendar(curYear, curMonth, day);
    minDaysInFirstWeek = forDay.getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek();
    return minDaysInFirstWeek;
}
```

Comment: First tip when using java's Calendar - don't use java's Calendar. Use [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) if you are using java8, or [joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) otherwise. The `Calendar` API is broken and poorly designed.

Comment: I cannot find a method `getMinDaysFirstWeek()`, so I assume you are talking of `Calenader.getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()`. Did you actually read the API documentation of `Calendar.getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()`? It returns how many days are required in a possibly incomplete first week of a year in order to be counted as first week of the year. I do not understand what a month has to do with that. Could you clarify these parts of your question?

Comment: Christian you right. i didnt notice it.

Comment: can you advice me any other option? to know for each month the user enter how many days are in the first week?

Comment: Hi Udi, can you please explain again what you code suppose to do? what you try to achieve.. and what is "minimal days of the first week" first week in a given year? first week in a given year and month? Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently i had a mistake like Christian Hujer mention.
the method getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() doesn't support what i ment to do.

i edit the code:

```
public int getDayInFirstWeek(int curYear , int curMonth , int day)
{
    Calendar forDay = new GregorianCalendar(curYear, curMonth, day);
    dayFirstWeek = forDay.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    return dayFirstWeek;
}
```

now it brings me back the first day of the week of each month the user input. 
thanks.